# Make a buffer-local variable become global again

Tags: elisp, local-variables, buffer-local

I was experimenting with local variables and set:

```
(defvar-local foo nil "Buffer local foo")
```

I later redesigned my program to use a global variable instead using:

```
(defvar foo nil "Not buffer local foo")
```

but the variable is still buffer local and even `(kill-local-variable 'foo)` didn't kill it.

Basically, how can I "undo" `make-local-variable`?

Comment: Just FWI, defvar-local uses `make-variable-buffer-local` not `make-local-variable`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The comment from @Malabarba explains your problem.

`kill-local-variable` *does* get rid of the local variable binding. But since in your case the variable is *automatically* local in any buffer, when you reassign it a value, that value is local.

AFAIK, there is no way to counter `make-variable-buffer-local`, except to use `unintern` on the symbol.  (`makunbound` does not help.)

If you use unintern then you're OK. But keep in mind that uninterning removes the symbol altogether, so if you used the symbol for something else, besides a variable, then there might be negative consequences.

So the only answer I have is to use `unintern` and then reassign the variable whatever value you want - it will be a global value.